# Does a signal that doesn't change polarity charge a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, uart, polarity, zero-crossing

I'm wondering if a digital signal that does not change polarity charges a capacitor.

If the signal has a frequency of 1 MHz, does that charge the capacitor faster? And if so, is it possible to discharge the capacitor by zerocrossing the signal? I have tried simulating in LT-spice, but I can only simulate for 1 minute. In practice I have a circuit that passes a UART signal with a 1 MHz frequency for about 4 hours  straight through a capacitor in series.

Secretly I hope the capacitor does not effect the UART signal, because adding a circuit for zerocrossing adds (logically) more components to the PCB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the signal has a frequency of 1 Mhz, does that charge the capacitor
> faster?

No.

> is it possible to discharge the capacitor by zerocrossing the signal?

Sure, if you do it with the right timing.

> Secretly I hope the capacitor does not effect the UART signal, because
> adding a circuit for zerocrossing adds (logically) more components to
> the PCB.

The capacitor **does** affect the UART signal. If the load is symmetrical then the capacitor will charge up to the average voltage of the signal and the output will cross zero at this average. Since the average voltage of a UART signal varies depending on the data, the zero crossing point will vary with it.

But each frame has a start and stop bit, so whenever data is present at least 1 negative pulse will be generated per frame. You can use this to 'DC restore' the signal so it doesn't go below ground. All you have to do is put a diode between the output and ground, which charges the capacitor up to the peak signal voltage to provide the required offset, like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnjNF9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each time the signal goes low it will cause the diode to conduct if the output goes below ground by more than ~0.3 V (Schottky diode forward voltage drop) which charges the capacitor up and raises the 'low' output voltage to ~0.3 V below ground. A high speed Schottky signal diode should be used for minimal voltage drop and low capacitance.

Depending on the receiver circuit you may find that this occurs even without a diode, because most digital logic ICs have protection diodes on their inputs to prevent negative voltage spikes from destroying them. However these diodes are usually very small and have a low current rating, so an external diode is recommended even if the circuit seems to work without it.

Comment: That is very clever, and it only adds one extra component.

Maybe a bit out of the blue, but a schmitt trigger IC might add the same functionality, plus an extra feature to tighten the data. I am interested in your idea about this.

Comment: @joggem a UART outputs a logical 1 (5 volts for instance) when idling so, when a start bit transition occurs the clamp diode and capacitor eat up that pulse and damage that initial start bit. I don't think this will work as you expect it to but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: A schmitt trigger just adds hysteresis to the input of a comparator, which is useful for rejecting low level noise and 'squaring up' a degraded signal. It won't fix AC coupled level issues (in fact it can make them worse because the schmitt trigger needs a larger voltage swing).

Comment: It looks like the OP will accept the answer that makes them happiest LOL.

Comment: The first bit of a transmission may be lost if the driver isn't strong enough to charge the capacitor quickly. To get around this you can send a 'preamble' that the receiver ignores or throws away (this often has to be done anyway if the receiver was disconnected or powered down between transmissions). Another option could be to send a 'break' before each transmission, which the receiver should ignore or use to synchronize to the signal. If you transmit data 'continuously' (ie. often enough to keep the capacitor charged) this isn't necessary.

Comment: What I was looking for is a solution with as less as posible components, so this fitted right in. Will be trying the diode solution tomorrow and see if the first start bit is a problem. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @Joggem the key word in what you say above is "solution". Think about it.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the forum, this is my first post and the answers where overwhelming, in a positive way! But from what I understand a OP can mark one answer as "accepted" if it works for OP. If it is because I'm looking for a "solution", I could have explained it better in my question. Thank you again for the affort for simulating, hopefully this points what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

> *Secretly I hope the capacitor does not effect the UART signal, because
> adding a circuit for zerocrossing adds (logically) more components to
> the PCB.*

Well, your secret is out now and be prepared for disappointment. The capacitor will wreak havoc on a UART signal because it will try to remove the DC offset of your UART signal. Given that a UART signal carries information as DC levels, you will have a problem.

Regarding the capacitor coupling and diode restoration idea, the biggest problem it faces (as I see it) is when the first start bit arrives after a period of bus inactivity: -

[image]

What you would like to see is this: -

[image]

But, what you see is this: -

[image]

In other words, the 1st start bit is corrupted in the first byte received after a period of "comms idle". Additionally, you have progressively lost (along the way) the logic 1 associated with "comms idle".

Comment: You're raising a point I forgot. UART is not sensible without reference voltages! +1.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. Does zero-crossing the UART signal fixes this problem?

Comment: @Joggem not really. In extreme situations the signal may not pass through 0 volts (like when a new UART transmission occurs after several seconds of inactivity). The best plan is don't couple with a capacitor.

Comment: Then I should find a combination of manchester coding (as Marcus suggested) and zero crossing.

Comment: Manchester encoding is good. So is data scrambling. So is FSK.

Comment: The problem is you need to have continuous data stream, or if you have pause between data bytes, then you must charge up the capacitance with a preamble before actual data packet, and by that time it is not sure if the byte framing is in sync any more, and if you again pause for longer than one frame to get back into byte sync, the capacitor charge/discharge time must be much longer than one data frame.

Comment: Thank you for simulating!

Comment: @Joggem Just some more info here if you wanna google.  This diode/resistor DC restore concept is one historically used in analog television and called a "sync tip clamp".  The thing to know is that it only can work under a specific set of constraints.  They were able get it work for TVs by fitting it within the timing pattern of each line/field, and also minimizing line tilt/droop (i.e. maximizing hum rejection) by selecting the correct capacitor & resistor.  If you can do similar for your UART signal, it can work.  If not, you need to employ more sophisticated "DC Restoration" circuitry.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKu4mt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The charge of a capacitor is the integral of current that has flown; that's all there is. So, no, a 1 MBd UART signal doesn't charge a capacitor faster. On the contrary, for high-speed signals, you'd be sure that your receiver has a defined impedance, and that will inherently be a DC path to ground.

By the way, "digital signal" is a bit confusing here, I think we understand what you mean, but everything that is a signal going through a capacitor is an analog thing - it just transports digital data.

I'm not quite sure why an UART should charge a capacitor close to the driver? The thing drives the output high, then low, then high, then low – every time it's driven low, that necessarily discharges the capacitor.

You'll find series capacitors in a lot of digital serial links, for example PCIe. The problem with them is that if your rate becomes too low, they get full charged, and then their output starts to effectively float and drift. So, in such a system, you must always ensure a minimum rate of high/low transitions per second – but that's really all. Things like manchester coding with sending data during idle works well enough for simpler links.